Proving Tightness for Exponentially Decaying Functions Family
Question:
I'm working through the concept of tightness from "Royden and Fitzpatrick" for the following family of functions:
Given the family:
$$
\mathcal{F}_2 = \{ f : \exists C > 0, \exists \alpha > 0, \forall x, |f(x)| \leq C e^{-\alpha |x|} \},
$$
where all functions are measurable on  $\mathbb{R}$ , is this family tight?
Definition:
A family $ \mathcal{F} $ of measurable functions on a set $ E $ is tight if, for every
$\epsilon > 0 $, there exists a measurable subset $ E_0 \subseteq E $ with finite measure such that:
$$
\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{E \setminus E_0} |f| < \epsilon.
$$
My Thoughts:
Since the functions decay exponentially, it seems intuitive that most of their "mass" is concentrated near the origin. However, I'm unsure how to rigorously prove this using the definition of tightness.
Could someone clarify how to approach this proof?
